# Return rows where Column A is either unique or the last occurrence of duplicate values

Tags: google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15xzwTJxxTuvWoMOgwGyMZk2BSknc9wD6iEUaZcOk03M/edit?usp=sharing

I'm inputted some fake data in this sheet which shows you the results I want.

'Data' sheet has my raw data.

The 'Filter' sheet includes values I don't want to show in the result at all.

The 'Results' sheet shows the results I'm looking for.

I want to filter rows in my 'Data' sheet using a query formula that will only return rows where column A is unique or column A is the LAST occurrence of a duplicate value.

Then I want to remove any rows where column A contains a value found in the 'Filter!:A:A' column.

The end results should look like the 'Results' sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I split the explanation into two parts, for simplicity describing the case when all data is in one sheet: A:B columns with raw data, and D column with what needs to be filtered out. In cell F1 put the following formula, which will create a list of Ids without repetition, also filtering out the contents of D:

```
=unique(filter(filter(A:A, len(A:A)), isna(match(filter(A:A, len(A:A)), filter(D:D, len(D:D)), 0))))
```

The filters by length exclude empty cells. The `match` returns N/A when the Id is not found in column  D. Only these are returned by the outer filter, with condition `isna(match(...))`. Finally, `unique` eliminates repetitions.

After the list of unique Ids is created, it's time to put the data next to it. This is done in cell G1:

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(filter(F:F, len(F:F)), sort({A:B, row(A:A)}, 3, false), 2, false))
```

The main idea is to use `vlookup` to look up each Id from column A in the table A:B. It returns the last entry found. Since you want the last entry found, the order in table A:B is reversed by sorting the entries by row number in decreasing order: `sort({A:B, row(A:A)}, 3, false)`. Then `arrayformula(vlookup(...))` performs the lookups for each entry of F column, returning the fruit name.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to soup's answer, and assuming your data in A:B, see if this works ?

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(unique(A:A), sort({A:B, row(A:A) }, 3, 0), {1,2}, 0)))
```